# JTable inside a JPanel inside a JOptionPane won't resize as wanted

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, joptionpane

I have two `JTable` objects inside a `JPanel` with `GridLayout`. I put them in a `JOptionPane` and I show them as an `OK_CANCEL` popup. I also put a `JScrollPane` on both tables.

However, the `JOptionPane`'s size is enormous. I have tried setting different table, scroll pane and jpanel sizes with:

```
table.setSize(int w, int h)
jpanel.setSize(int w, int h)
jscrollpane.setSize(int w, int h)
```

but none of those would result in a smaller `JOptionPane` (or table).

This is how it looks, I use 1366*768 as resolution. None of the mentioned above would make any difference

[image: This is how it looks]

```
private void showEditItemSuppliersDialog()
    {
    String newItemSupplierTables [] = { "#", "Name", "" };
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2, 5, 5));

        /* table 1 */
        allItemsEditItemSuppliersTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(null, newItemSupplierTables);

        allItemsEditItemSuppliersTable = new JTable(allItemsEditItemSuppliersTableModel);
        allItemsEditItemSuppliersTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        JScrollPane allItemsEditItemSuppliersTableScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        allItemsEditItemSuppliersTableScrollPane.setViewportView(allItemsEditItemSuppliersTable);
        /* table 1 end */

        /* table 2 */
        allItemsEditItemSuppliersAllTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(null, newItemSupplierTables);

        allItemsEditItemSuppliersAllTable = new JTable(allItemsEditItemSuppliersAllTableModel);
        allItemsEditItemSuppliersAllTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        JScrollPane allItemsEditItemSuppliersAllTableScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        allItemsEditItemSuppliersAllTableScrollPane.setViewportView(allItemsEditItemSuppliersAllTable);
        /* table 2 end*/

        panel.add(allItemsEditItemSuppliersTableScrollPane);
        panel.add(allItemsEditItemSuppliersAllTableScrollPane);

        int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, "Edit", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

        if (option == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
        {   
            System.out.println("Pressed OK");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the preferred viewport size of the tables using [setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(Dimension)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setPreferredScrollableViewportSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29).

Comment: Thank you, as soon as I can accept the answer I will as this was what I needed.